# Issue with AWS Client VPN on AWS Workspace connecting to the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I have a Ubuntu AWS Workspace. On it I connect to my VPC using AWS Client VPN. This allows me to access local resources but the public internet doesn't work. When I am not connected to using the AWS Client VPN the public internet works.

On my local Macbook, when connected to the same AWS Client VPN, both local resources and public internet work.

The AWS VPN has split tunnelling enabled.

Comment: When the Client VPN is not enabled does internet access work? If it's split tunnel the internet traffic shouldn't touch the Client VPN. There may be alternate simpler and cheaper ways to access a VPC, for example over Transit Gateway or VPC peering.

Comment: @Tim When the Client VPN is not enabled the internet does work. I am assuming the VPN is configured correctly as on our local laptops the internet works when connected to the VPN and not. It's only on the AWS Workspace this is an issue.

Comment: Interesting. Have you had a look at the Ubuntu routing table while the Client VPN is on and when it's off (link below)? Please do that, edit your question to show both if you can't see a difference. Also please show some diagnostics, such as ping to internal / external resources with VPN on and off. Lastly perhaps show us the Client VPN configuration, specifically when split tunnel is set up. https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-display-routing-table.html